# Is it possible to auto-renew a trade route?

Tags: civilization-5-brave-new-world

In brave new world trade routes have been completely reworked and a caravan or cargo ship unit is now needed to maintain a trade route.

Every few turns the trade route needs to be set up again, optionally going to a different target.

Is it possible to set a trade unit to keep going to the same target until told otherwise, so it doesn't ask for a new destination every few turns, requiring less micromanagement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not possible. It may become possible in the future with use of mods. But as it stands now, the game does not have this functionality.